# How to calculate total of defs using django?

Tags: python, django

I would like to calculate the total balance of clients, i did this class with def but it calculate for one client only, i would like to create one def to calculate the total of `client_balance` of all clients i have.

```
class ClientsBalance(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Client')

    def sales(self):
        invoices = self.client.invoice_set.all()
        sales_amount = 0
        for invoice in invoices:
            sales_amount += invoice.amountDuettc()
        return sales_amount

    def clientpayment(self):
        invoices = self.client.invoice_set.all()
        clientpayment = 0
        for invoice in invoices:
            clientpayment += invoice.amount_paid()
        return clientpayment

    def client_balance(self):
        items = self.client.invoice_set.all()
        invoice_balance = 0
        for item in items:
            invoice_balance = (self.sales()) - (self.clientpayment()) + (item.client.initialBalance)
        return invoice_balance
```

Comment: it's `invoice_balance += ..` isn't it? Right now it returns the balance of the last client in the Queryset?

Comment: This returning balance of last client. initialise a empty dictionary. Append dictionary in every iteration in loop with key of client_pk and value invoice_balance.

Comment: client_balance is for each client, I would like to have the total of all clients i have

Comment: Don't you just want something like `sum(cb.client_balance() for cb in ClientBalance.objects.all())`? But I don't see why you have a seperate model here for the client balance, if its only field is a reference to the `Client` model.

Comment: Why you are not using 'aggregate' with 'sum' function to calculate all values in the query. `self.objects.aggregate(Sum('invoices'))` <-example

Comment: where i can put it exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo in your function which makes each iteration overwriting `invoice_balance`.

This will return the sum as desired:

```
def client_balance(self):
    items = self.client.invoice_set.all()
    invoice_balance = 0
    for item in items:
        invoice_balance += (self.sales()) - (self.clientpayment()) + (item.client.initialBalance)
    return invoice_balance
```

Second of all you could merge your logic if required since you always use the same queryset like so e.g.:

```
def calculations(self):

    queryset = self.client.invoice_set.all()

    sales_amount = 0
    clientpayment = 0
    invoice_balance = 0

    for client in queryset:
        sales_amount += client.amountDuettc()
        clientpayment += client.amount_paid()
        invoice_balance += client.amountDuettc() - client.clientpayment() + client.client.initialBalance()

    context = {
        'sales_amount': sales_amount,
        'clientpayment': clientpayment,
        'invoice_balance': invoice_balance
    }

    return context
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. but i cannot get the answer i need, this is for each clients, but for me i need the sum of all clients balance in one column

Answer (score -1):

You current logic is returning balance of last client. In every iteration, invoice_balance override the previous value.

Try this.
Initialize an empty dictionary and append dictionary in every iteration:

```
def client_balance(self):
    items = self.client.invoice_set.all()
    invoice_dict = {}
    for item in items:
        invoice_balance = (self.sales()) - (self.clientpayment()) + (item.client.initialBalance)
        invoice_dict[client_pk] = invoice_balance # client_pk is something unique for client.
    return invoice_dict
```

This will return an dictionary with invoice balance of every client.

Comment: This is by no means a solid answer to the OP's question..